# Run-time error 440 VB6

Tags: vb6

I have created an exe program based on ocx file and I used VB Package & Deployment wizard to install the exe file as a program on a non vb environment, the problem is I am getting this error when running the program

"RUN TIME ERROR '440' AUTOMATION ERROR.

What do you think is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 440 Automation error usually indicates that one (or more) COM object failed to load.

This might be an ActiveX exe, ocx, or maybe one of the external dependencies you included in your project.

Make sure all the external libraries you use are registered correctly on the system that's giving the error.

You can test this by registering the ActiveX (.ocx, .exe), and COM components (usually .dll) manually.

**ATL/COM, ActiveX EXE, OCX, DLL**

If the target assembly is a COM/ATL assembly, you can use `regsvr32.exe` (located in windows\system32 directory) for the `ocx` files and the COM- `dll`s. You can register an ActiveX-`exe` by running it with the option `/regserver` see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297279 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146219

**.NET ComVisible**

If the target assembly is a *.net* assembly which uses `ComVisible`, you can register it with `regasm.exe`, it is somewhere in the .NET framework directory. see: [How to register a .NET assembly as COM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322353/how-to-register-a-net-assembly-as-com)

**Or else**

You might want to use a tool like `dependency walker` to check which registration and dll's are missing from your system.You can download it from here, http://dependencywalker.com/ beware, run downloaded exe's at your own risk.

Comment: How can i register them manualy sir? all i know is to register the ocx manualy I only know how to reg ocx by using regsvr32

Comment: Use regsvr32 for the ocx files and the COM-dlls. You can register an ActiveX-exe by running it with the option `/regserver`

see:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297279
and
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146219

Comment: PS. If your project uses a .NET ComVisible dll, you'll need RegAsm.exe, it is somewhere in the .NET framework directory. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322353/how-to-register-net-assembly-as-com/11322592#11322592