# Adding VLC Media Player to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, winforms, vlc

I am trying to get the VLC Media Player ActiveXPlugin V2 into my WindowsForms Application. 
I've registered the axvlc.dll and added it as reference to my project. 
But I can't get the control into my toolbox.

I've read that I simply have to right ckilck into the toolbox and select "choose items" then navigate to "COM components" and select the "VLC Active X Plugin V2", but it is not listed!

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is your com registered? If not you can try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401873/run-time-error-440-vb6/19402159#19402159

Comment: @Stefan Doesn't work: "axvlc.dll could not be loaded because it is not a valid .NET-Assembly".
Furthermore this Tip from the VLC page doesn't work either :%WINDIR%\Microsoft.net\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm VLanControl.dll /codebase because command is not found

Comment: If it is com you'll need `regsvr32.exe`

Comment: @Stefan I already did that successfully, but it still doesn't show up under COM components

Comment: And `regasm` is definitely present if you have a .net framework installed. Maybe you've got the path's or version incorrect.

Comment: You might need to refresh the com cache in visual studio, maybe restarting vs2015 will help to make it show. Usually it takes a while to gather all COM components from a system, so vs2015 caches this lookup.

Comment: @Stefan I restarted VS15 several times and also the computer

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you can also add the com reference by `add reference` and browse to the actual file.

Comment: Yes, but then I still don't have the control in my toolbox

Comment: Did you try the Browse button in the Choose Toolbox Items dialog? I have VLC installed (did not regsvr32 anything) (my axvlc.dll is v2.2.4) and chose mine from "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\axvlc.dll", did not add any references (it adds them automatically after draging the component from the toolbox). Tried reinstalling VLC? Which .NET version is your assembly?

Comment: @Fixation Yes I did. When I start VS15 with admin rights and search for the axvlc.dll in the COM Tab I get an error: "Self registration for C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\axvlc.dll failed." I am using v2.2.4 too. 
I even unregistered it with regsvr32 but I still get that message. And yes I reinstalled VLC several times. What version of MS Studio are you using ?

Comment: @B.Ueno don't add the solution to the question.  Make an answer and add it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using VLC x64 for my Win 10 x64 System. But apparently the VLC ActiveX Plugin doesn't work with VisualStudio 15 when VLC x64 is installed.

-> Installed VLC x32 and it works now