# Using dll of .Net by VB6 app in Windows 8

Tags: .net, vb6, com-interop

I place my Vb6 app and all the 'dll' files in the folder like this **"D:\TestVb6"**. Vb6 app will reference to 'dll' of .Net.

I have registered the 'dll' files by using 'Regasm.exe' and the Vb6 app working fine in Windows 7. But when i do that in Window 8, the Vb6 app has errors. 
Then i try to copy all 'dll' files into the folder **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98"** and the Vb6 app work correctly.

I wondering why in Window 8 I have to place all 'dll' files in the folder **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98"** ?
And If I want to place the 'dll' files in another folder, how can i do that ?

Anyone can help me! Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to register .net assembly as COM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322353/how-to-register-net-assembly-as-com). Look at the `/codebase` switch.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to put your directory to your path environment variable. So Windows would look into that directory automatically.